# Trying to use GDAL in Windows Apache WSGI with Python 3.9.5 from OSGeo4W

Tags: gdal, python-3, osgeo4w, apache

Not much is missing and I'm going crazy. I'm pulling my hair out to get GDAL running under WSGI in Windows Apache using a Python 3.9.5 Installation from OSGeo4W.

I have installed QGIS 3.24.2 with GDAL 3.4.2 using osgeo4w-setup.exe. When I open the OSGeo4W Shell an run following Python lines of code, everything works as expected.

[image]

But when I run the code in my WSGI Python application function, I get an error which tells me `DLL load failed while importing _gdal`.

```
  File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-web-client/wsgi/wmservice.py", line 61, in <module>\r
    from osgeo import gdal,osr,ogr\r
  File "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\GDAL-3.4.2-py3.9-win-amd64.egg\\osgeo\\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>\r
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()\r
  File "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\GDAL-3.4.2-py3.9-win-amd64.egg\\osgeo\\__init__.py", line 42, in swig_import_helper\r
    return importlib.import_module('_gdal')\r
  File "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module\r
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'\r
mod_wsgi (pid=3444): Failed to exec Python script file 'C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-web-client/wsgi/wmservice.py'.
mod_wsgi (pid=3444): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-web-client/wsgi/wmservice.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):\r
  File "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\GDAL-3.4.2-py3.9-win-amd64.egg\\osgeo\\__init__.py", line 29, in swig_import_helper\r
    return importlib.import_module(mname)\r
  File "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module\r
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 666, in _load_unlocked\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 565, in module_from_spec\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1173, in create_module\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _gdal: The specified procedure could not be found.\r
\r
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r
\r
Traceback (most recent call last):\r
  File "C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis-web-client/wsgi/wmservice.py", line 61, in <module>\r
    from osgeo import gdal,osr,ogr\r
  File "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\GDAL-3.4.2-py3.9-win-amd64.egg\\osgeo\\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>\r
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()\r
  File "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\GDAL-3.4.2-py3.9-win-amd64.egg\\osgeo\\__init__.py", line 42, in swig_import_helper\r
    return importlib.import_module('_gdal')\r
  File "C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module\r
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_gdal'\r
```

Next you see an extract from my *wmservice.py* file (until gdal will be imported).

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# set Environment variables
import os,sys
os.environ['PATH'] = 'C:\\OSGEO4W64\\bin;C:\\OSGEO4W64\\apps\\qgis\\bin;C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\qt5\\bin;C:\\OSGEO4~1\\apps\\Python39\\Scripts;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\system32\\WBem'
os.environ['PYTHONHOME'] = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39'
os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\qgis\\python;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39;C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\Python39\\Scripts;'
os.environ['GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8'] = 'YES'
os.add_dll_directory(r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin')
os.environ['GDAL_DRIVER_PATH'] = r'C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\gdalplugins'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = r'D:\Python-Egg-Cache'
os.environ['USE_PATH_FOR_GDAL_PYTHON'] = 'YES'

sys.path.insert(0,'C:/OSGeo4W64/bin')
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Python39')
sys.path.append('C:/OSGEO4W64/apps/qgis/bin')
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/Python39/Scripts')
sys.path.append('C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/python')
sys.path.append('C:/Windows/system32')
sys.path.append('C:/Windows')
sys.path.append('C:/Windows/system32/WBem')

os.environ['GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH'] = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal304.dll'
os.environ['GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH'] = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\geos_c.dll'

## Important !! set GDAL_DATA in global Windows Environment
## Unfortunately, setting it here does not help !!
#os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = r'C:\OSGEO4W64\share\gdal'
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = r'C:\OSGEO4W64\share\proj'


from osgeo import gdal,osr,ogr
```

P.S.: I used *os.environ* and *sys.path* to set Windows PATH, because I didn't know which one will be used.

I have absolutely no idea what's missing here. I checked all file permissions and even installed GDAL from Christoph Gohlke ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs)), unfortunately without luck. Using Gohlkes installation, Python GDAL claims to have no PDF driver support, but *gdalinfo.exe* works without any problem.

Maybe someone can shade some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many hours of trial and error, before giving up, I made one last attempt that finally solved the problem.

I removed the OSGeo4W *GDAL* installation from `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python39\Lib\site-packages` and installed GDAL from Christoph Gohlke's site (GDAL-3.4.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl). With this installation the GDAL DLL was found and loaded, but PDF support was missing.

In the next step I copied ***gdal304.dll*** and all **other DLLs** from `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin`to `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python39\Lib\site-packages\osgeo` and the problem was solved.